# C++ Eigen avoid or detect division by zero in broadcast function

Tags: c++, linear-algebra, eigen

Given a real symmetric matrix *A* I am computing the eigenvectors for the matrix

[image]

where *D* is a diagonal matrix where entry *D(i,i)* is the sum of row *i* of *A*. Then analysis is performed as follows:

```
Eigen::VectorXf D = A.rowwise().sum().array().rsqrt();
Eigen::MatrixXf L = D.asDiagonal()*A*D.asDiagonal();
Eigen::SelfAdjointEigenSolver<Eigen::MatrixXf> eigenSolver(N);
eigenSolver.compute(L);
_lambda.noalias() = eigenSolver.eigenvalues().reverse();
_X.noalias() = eigenSolver.eigenvectors().rowwise().reverse();
```

In some cases I am getting `NaN`'s for *all* the eigenvalues which I assume is due to the fact that some rows of *A* are zero and the broadcasted `rsqrt()` function is returning `NaN`
(division by zero). These entries should just be zero (or any number really) in this case.

Is there a way to avoid or alter these division's by zero and still broadcast `rsqrt`?
If `NaN * 0` was zero then this wouldn't be a problem.

Comment: N.B., `rsqrt(0) == inf`, but `inf * 0 == NaN`

Comment: OK -- that is why I was getting NaN's --- thx

Answer (score 1):

Adding a tiny bit to each diagonal element resolve this issue:

```
constexpr float eps = std::numeric_limits<float>::epsilon();
Eigen::VectorXf D = (Apermuted.rowwise().sum().array() + eps).rsqrt();
```

Comment: `epsilon` might be quite large compared to entries in your matrix. You could instead try `std::numeric_limits<float>::min()` -- but probably it does not matter in your case.

Comment: Yes -- since sqrt(min) can't underflow that should be better -- thx.